# How can I travel to the "Eye of the Sahara"? Are there tours? Can I self-guide?

Tags: tours, landmarks, self-guided

The [Richat Structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richat_Structure), or "Eye of the Sahara", only just appeared on my travel radar.  It's new to me - and in an exciting part of Africa - Mauritania.

What I'm lacking information on is how one could theoretically get there, either self-guided or as part of a tour? Information appreciated.

[image]

Comment: wow that image is cool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the below information from [an article on a travel site called "The Circumference"](http://www.thecircumference.org/richat-structure). I've put the gist from that site here for easy reading.

- Best time to visit the Eye is around December.
- May be reached through several access countries like Mali, Niger and Mauritania.
- Tours can be booked in Atar, Mauritania which include four wheel drive to Richat and hot-air balloon tour. Tours from Atar tend to be costly as travel operators are more established as compared to those that are operating inland.
- Opting for a tour in Ouadane, Mauritania might work out cheaper which is closer to the Eye.

I couldn't find any information on camel rides/trekking/self guided trips to Richat structure. And no information of any tour operators either.

Answer (score 7):

The best I can find is how to get to [Chinguetti](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2079561&messageID=18709402#1870940).  You basically have to get to Atar then catch a taxi to Chinguetti.  After that you may be able to get a [camel tour](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2016481&messageID=18707859#18707859) to Eye of Sahara.

Although neither posts mentions trekking to Eye of Sahara but given the fact that you have to get the tours at Chinguetti or Atar lets me know that it may be possible to get the camel tour that goes to the Eye.

Comment: I'm the poster "szcax" from your second link. I can confirm that you can indeed get a camel tour to the Eye of the Sahara, but I didn't do it (the guides I was with suggested a price that was too expensive for me). What I did was start talking to people in Nouakchott, who in turn gave me names of people to talk to in Atar, who in turn set me up with people in Chinguetti -- everything very unofficial. If you take this approach, your mileage may vary. The tourism infrastructure in Mauritania is very sparse, so expect that you'll need to put some effort into making things happen this way.